# Shellscript - gzip multiple file and running all

Tags: shell, unix, gzip, solaris

Are there any suggestions for doing gzip multiple files and running simultaneously.
example:

`file_a.out
file_b.out
file_c.out
file_d.out`

*gzip process*

`gzip-f file_a.out
gzip-f file_b.out
gzip-f file_c.out
gzip-f file_d.out`

Running along with a script, is there any suggestions?

Thank you team :)

Comment: `for i in *.out; do gzip -f "$i" &; done`?

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU parallel.

```
parallel -j 8 < file.txt
```

where file.txt contains the list of commands

Comment: There's a lot of funky stuff you can do with parallel: "ls file* | parallel gzip" , or "parallel gzip ::: file*" are synonymous, with the advantage of the latter of not having to spawn an extra process.

Answer (score -1):

Start them in the background and then wait for each to finish.

```
gzip file1 &
gzip file2 &
gzip file3 &
wait
```